# Using "delete" operator on local variables

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project where there is a lot of delete operators at the end of almost every function, something like below:

```
var link = $$('a[href=#refresh]');
// do something more...
delete link;
```

I know that delete should be only used for object properties. My question is using delete in the way I mentioned slows down the code anyhow or has a negative performance impact?

Comment: It should be pretty much useless.

Comment: It will do exactly nothing. N.B. If the variables have been created in the global scope, e.g. by excluding `var`, delete will work.

Comment: All "removed" variables are in a function scope. So I guess they should be automatically deleted after function ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)*** explain `delete` very well.

> delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has **no effect
>   on variable or function names**. While sometimes mischaracterized as
>   global variables, assignments that don't specify an object (e.g. x =
>   5) are actually property assignments on the global object.
>
> delete can't remove certain properties of predefined objects (like
>   Object, Array, Math etc). These are described in ECMAScript 5 and
>   later as non-configurable.

Comment: Deleting a link variable in my example would simply return "false", and I know that it shouldn't be used in the way it is. As I said, it's not my code so the only thing I'm curious about is if such usage of delete slows down that code.